# Updating Widget in GtkVBox

Tags: gtk

I have a GtkVBox with some labels and some empty blocks in it ...
I have created this window + vBox in Glade3... Working under C.

```
+----------------+
|Lable1          |  
+----------------+
|EMPTY           |  
+----------------+
|Label2          |  
+----------------+
|Lable3          |  
+----------------+
```

On some external events i want to add a label widget at the EMPTY place...
How to do it?

Plus, how can i remove any of the label and add new widget at that place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just add an empty (or hidden) label initially, and then populate it or show it  when needed?

To remove the label, use [`gtk_container_remove`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.11/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) (vbox, label), where *vbox* is a pointer to the GtkVBox widget and *label* is a pointer the widget you want to remove.

Comment: Actually requirement is such that ..... some times i need to place label or some times i need to place image and on top of the image i need to place label... so kept it empty... can we update displayed image to some other image.. suppose Empty place holds some invisible image then on some event i will replace this image with visible image.. can we do this and how to do this?

Comment: You can add an empty GtkVBox in that place, and then call gtk_box_pack_start() to add the widget you want when needed. If you need to change it later, destroy the contents of the box and pack the new widgets.